# Highcharts - Add difference between y-points

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How I can add difference between two points?
For example for 'monday' Jane has 1, John has 3 points so John should have info like "(-70%)", in Wednesday John has 3, Jane has 4 so it should be "(+125%)"
Info should be at line which is nearest right side.

[image]
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-inverted/)

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area',
                inverted: true
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
            },
            subtitle: {
                style: {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    right: '0px',
                    bottom: '10px'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -150,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Monday',
                    'Tuesday',
                    'Wednesday',
                    'Thursday',
                    'Friday',
                    'Saturday',
                    'Sunday'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of units'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                },
                min: 0
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand calculation:
- Jane = 1, 
- John = 3, so label = (-70%)

However, this is way to get dataLabel for Jane and John:

```
                formatter: function(){
                    var secondY = this.series.chart.series[1].yData[this.point.x],
                        firstY = this.y;
                    return this.y;    
                }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gvuA/

Comment: It's exactly what i need. Thanks Paweł. You saved me once again
My updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gvuA/1/